# How do I find which elements in one array aren't in another?

Tags: perl

I am new to programming and hence I am stuck on a basic level problem.

Following is code I wrote for comparison. But the result I get does not make sense to me. I would appreciate if someone could tell me what is going wrong.

There are two arrays: `@array1` , `@array2` of unequal length.

I wish to compare both and list down values not present in @array1.

```
my %temp = map {$_,$_}@array2;
for (@array1){
next if exists $temp{$_};
open (FILE, ">>/filename") or die "$!";
print FILE "$_\n";
close(FILE);
}
```

Comment: Show also your input, your output, and your expected output.

Comment: The why is usually an essential element for such novice questions, otherwise those of us helping can't identify "X-Y problems".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the FAQ [How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays%3f--How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays%3f)

Adapting the code you posted:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @x = 1 .. 10;
my @y = grep { $_ % 2 } @x;

my %lookup = map { $_ => undef } @y;

for my $x ( @x ) {
    next if exists $lookup{$x};
    print "$x\n";
}
```

Comment: I usually do `my %seen; @seen{@y} = (1) x @y;` instead of `map`, but they amount to the same thing.

Comment: @Ether - Because microoptimization is fun, my becnhmarks show that as being slightly faster than `map`. Clever _and_ efficient.

Comment: I can't resist using hash slices! :)

Comment: @Chris Lutz, `my %seen; @seen{@y} = ();` is even faster and saves memory. Ugly as hell, though, and you gotta use `exists`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're doing this for a test, which I assume you are I would highly suggest [is_deeply](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Test::More#is_deeply) in the newer versions of Test::More

You'll have to update Test::More

```
cpanp install Test::More
```

or if you're on perl 5.5

```
cpan Test::More
```

Then you'll have use it

```
use Test::More;
tests => 1
is_deeply ( \@arr1, \@arr2, 'test failed' );
```

If you're not doing this for testing, but you're doing this for introspective purposes and the arrays are small, I'd suggest using [XXX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XXX):

```
cpanp install http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/I/IN/INGY/XXX-0.12.tar.gz
```

Then you'll have use it

```
use XXX;
YYY [ \@arr1, \@arr2 ];
```

Answer (score 4):

That's some pretty clever code you've got there. Your code is more or less identical to what the Perl FAQ says. I might be tempted to do this, however:

```
my %tmp  = map  { $_ => 1 } @array2;
my @diff = grep { not exists $tmp{$_} } @array1;
```

This gets everything in `@array1` that's not in `@array2`, but avoiding all of those out-of-style looping constructs (yay for functional programming). Though what I'd *really* do is this:

```
sub comp (\@\@) {
  my %t = map { $_ => 1 } @{$_[1]};
  return grep { not exists $t{$_} } @{$_[0]};
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
my @diff = comp(@array1, @array2); # get items in @array1 not in @array2
@diff = comp(@arraty2, @array1); # vice versa
```

Or you can go to [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~jkeenan/List-Compare-0.37/lib/List/Compare/Functional.pm). `List::Compare::Functional::complement()` does what you want, though the syntax is reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Swap `@array1` and `@array2` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

For simple values like strings or numbers, the following should work

```
my @result;
my $hosts = [qw(host1 host2 host3 host4 host5)];
my $stie_obj = [qw(host1 host5 host6)];

@result = map { my $a=$_; my $b=grep {/$a/} @$site_obj; $b==0 ? $a : () } @$hosts;
print Dumper (@result);
```

Should give :

```
$VAR1 = 'host2';
$VAR2 = 'host3';
$VAR3 = 'host4';
```