# How to print the elements, which are not present in both arrays?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find which elements in one array aren't in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759418/how-do-i-find-which-elements-in-one-array-arent-in-another)

```
@a=qw(one two three four five six);
@b=qw(zero one two three four seven);
```

I expect to print:

```
zero five six seven
```

These elements are not present in both arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@a=qw(one two three four five six);
@b=qw(zero one two three four seven);

$words{$_}++ for (@a, @b);
while (($k, $v) = each %words) {
    next if $v > 1;
    print "$k ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @b;

while( my $el = shift @a )
{
    print $el unless defined $hash{ $el };
    $hash{ $el } = 0;        
}

foreach( keys %hash )
{
    print $_ if $hash{ $_ } == 1;
}
```

edit: changed $_ to $el and removed 'print' in while

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a=qw(one two three four five six); 
my @b=qw(zero one two three four seven);
my %seen;
foreach my $a (@a) {
  $seen{$a} = 1;
}

foreach my $b (@b) {
  if (defined $seen{$b} and $seen{$b} == 1) {
    $seen{$b} = -1; 
  } else {
    $seen{$b} = 2;
  }
}

foreach my $k (keys %seen) {
  print "$k\n" if $seen{$k} != -1; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear.. It can solve my problem by this program.

Answer (score 0):

```
my %hash; $hash{$_}++ for @a,@b;
say join " ", grep { $hash{$_} == 1 } keys %hash;
```